# How can I place and handle a standard Windows button in Processing?

Tags: processing

Title says it all.

(more characters.)

Comment: The title does **not** say it all. What exactly is a standard Windows button? Where are you trying to place it? Also, **please** link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/18411/how-can-i-place-and-handle-a-standard-windows-button-in-processing

Comment: "What exactly is a standard Windows button?" Anyone who doesn't know (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dn742402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 ) should probably skip this question.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a standard Windows button. The whole point of the article you linked is explaining that there isn't a standard button. That is a guide explaining what your buttons should look like to make them standard. How you do that is up to you and the language you choose (in this case, Processing). But there isn't a "standard Windows button" tucked away somewhere.

There are buttons that you can display given the GUI features of a particular language, and there are look and feel properties you can set or implement in a particular language, but it doesn't really make sense to say that you want to "place and handle a standard Windows button."

Really what you're asking are two questions:

## Question 1: How can I show a button?

**Option 1:** Do it yourself. This would require you to draw the button at the correct location, and then detect click events for that button.

**Option 2:** Use a library. Libraries like ControlP5 or G4P are designed to allow you to create a GUI from Processing. More info available [here](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/).

**Option 3:** Don't use Processing. Use Swing, or JavaFX, or pretty much any other modern language. But again, that's just a matter of figuring out how to create a button in that language.

## Question 2: How can I make that button look like other buttons?

How you do this depends on which option you chose from the first question. If you do it yourself, then it's just a matter of painting the button however you want. If you're calling a library, then you might be able to set some properties to change how your button looks. If you're using Swing, then look into Swing Look and Feels. I'm sure other languages have similar features.

Word to the wise: I'd love to help you, but you come across as a bit rude when you post broad questions (which frankly should probably be closed instead of answered, but I tend to not be as strict as other Stack Overflow users) and then tell people to "skip this question" when they ask for more info. It's up to you how you want to present yourself, but I'd recommend giving the benefit of the doubt to people who are helping you, for free, in their spare time. But it's up to you how to proceed.